# Want to use generator to my voice bot to improve NLU performance. Can anyone guide me on how to use this generator

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I have created a generator and Mapped to the specific page. I have inquired in Bard even then I am not getting proper response.

I want my bot to generate Dynamic responses so that bot performance is better than ever.If I enable generators in dfcx ,will  the bot be able to comprehend the Long Utterances and respond appropriately.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so with generators, you can create templates and use them in any part of the flows. In the generators you can access to:
$conversation - The conversation between the agent and the user, excluding the very last user utterance.
$last-user-utterance - The last user utterance.

Check the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/generators